# How to squish and squash x-axis hyperbolic tangent

Tags: linear-transformations, hyperbolic-functions

Consider the following equation:

> $$\frac{1}{2} (1 -\tanh[2(x-100)])$$

[image]

How can I modify the equation to adjust the steepness of the vertical-ish section centered about the line $x=100$? That is, how can I make the blue curve look more like the dark red curve, or vis versa.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of
$$
y= \frac{1}{2}(1-\tanh{\left(2[x-100]\right)})
$$
make it 
$$
y= \frac{1}{2}(1-\tanh{\left(\alpha[x-100]\right)})
$$
and adjust the value of $\alpha$.
Done.

Comment: Also, you can play with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e9dt1f8kro